# Count first occurrences in time (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
+----+---------------------+
| Id | Date application    | 
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | 2016-08-22 03:05:06 |
| 2  | 2016-08-22 03:05:06 |
| 1  | 2016-08-23 03:05:06 |
| 2  | 2016-08-23 03:05:06 |
+----+---------------------+
```

I would like to find out when was the first application for each user (ID) 
and then to count how many occurred in the past 7 days

so far here is what I have

```
SELECT id,  
min(date_of_application)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY date_of_application ASC
```

Will the min() work on dates ?
From there, how do I count how many first applications there are in the past 7 days ?

Comment: The first answer already mentioned this, but I'll elaborate - you really should include information about what database and version you are using. It's very important information for most SQL questions, since most databases are slightly different. (Example information: MySQL version 5.7) If it's a common database like oracle, mssql, mysql, or sqlite, then you should add that as a tag on the post.

Comment: From there, how do I count how many first applications there are in the past 7 days ? Would you please elaborate on this? Do you mean how many times each user accessed the application or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please tag your database. min() will work on dates.

Assuming your is mysql db here is what you can do to get the application usage count in the past 7 days from now.

```
select 
  id, count(*) as 'appUsageCount'
from 
  mytable
where 
    dateApplication      >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
and date_of_application  <= DATE(NOW()))
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

@Neeraj: Using your query with little modification.
Try this:

```
select 
  id, count(id) as 'appUsageCount', min(date_of_application)
from 
  mytable
where 
    date_of_application      >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
and date_of_application  <= DATE(NOW()))
group by id
```